# asp.net mvc modify default authentication system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am creating a new asp.net web application and I am selecting the template MVC with "Authentication: Individual Users Accounts". 
I had a look at the code generated for the authentication system and I don't understand where the fields for the AspNetUsers are created... I want to set relationships from this table(of users) to other tables in the database(created by me). I am using EF.

Do you know a way to modify the table AspNewUsers with EF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's in App_Data folder by default (Press *Show all files* in Solution explorer if it's not visible).

You can also change connection string of EF db context. By default, it's in *Web.config* file. Find *DefaultConnection* in *connectionStrings* tag.