# How to use a new SQL Server database for ASP.NET MVC default web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

First of all a similar question was asked on below link but since there is no satisfied and accepted answer I am asking again.

[asp.net mvc modify default authentication system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452555/asp-net-mvc-modify-default-authentication-system)

When I create a default ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2015, there is a default authentication system. It has also a database with tables. What I want to do is using my own database for the default authentication system, so I can integrate it to an application easily. I can create same tables in my database for it.

I tried to find some references to tables like AspNetUsers in the code but I couldn't find anything.

[image]

I always created database first and create model from it automatically in ASP.NET MVC. So always there is reference for my tables in my code. But default ASP.NET MVC application seems different.

Which part of the code I should modify and how?

And also why couldn't I find any reference to tables in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right, but I guess you Need to modify the Connection string in the web.config file - and use the Connection string of your db.

Comment: You could not find references for tables because they are implemented in default auth mechanism ;) there are few clases what you can extend to add more columns or tables to be handled by this engine like user profile subscriptions etc. ...

Comment: Which MVC version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The tables are created by default when creating the project because of authentication. 
If changed like this This table can not be created.

[image]

[image]

If you want to use authentication, you can use [Asp.net Identity](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1066062/Authentication-and-Authorization-using-Asp-net-Ide).